# WebRTC screen share in chrome(Retina MacBookPro) low frameRate

Tags: macos, webrtc, screen, share

I have a big problem when making a screen share demo between chrome browser depends on WebRTC.

Environment：**MacBookPro macOS 10.13.3**, **chrome: 64.0.3282.119**

In order to get screen media sourceId, I also make a chrome extention, the background-script.js code as follows:

```js
var screenOptions = ['screen', 'window'];
......
chrome.desktopCapture.chooseDesktopMedia(screenOptions, port.sender.tab, onAccessApproved);
```

When get media sourceId in my html javascript, a request screen media as follows:

```js
    var constraints = {
        video: {
            mandatory: {
                chromeMediaSource: 'desktop',
                maxWidth: 1280,
                maxHeight: 720,
                maxFrameRate: 30,
                minAspectRatio: 1.77,
                chromeMediaSourceId: sourceId
            }
        }
    };
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints).then(gotLocalStream).catch(function (e) {
        alert('getUserMedia() error: ' + e.name);
    });
```

The problem comes: when I inspect WebRTC stats in chrome://webrtc-internals, I found the googFrameRateInput was very low (<=10) when I play a video in main display, while googFrameRateInput can reach 30 when a do nothing in main display.

[googFrameRateInput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8u5xD.png)

I also try this in windows chrome, googFrameRateInput can reach 24~30 even when play a video.

Why googFrameRateInput is too low in mac chrome?

Thank a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Updating electron 6.0.2 solved the issue.